# Can't connect ODBC source to access my Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, odbc, tnsnames, tns

I'm trying to configure data source odbc to access to my database oracle.

I added new data source odbc , choice Oracle in XE. then appeare a window with some information to add.

- Data source name : mydatabase
- Description  :
- TNS Service name : ?
- User name : fatim

in TNS Service name I must choice from the list butI have a empty list .

so what's the problem?

can you please help me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At first you must install Oracle Client. Then in your StartMenu there will be "Oracle - OraClient" entry. From this menu run "Net Manager" and in its tree configure new "Service Naming". Such service naming will be in ODBC combo box for TNS Service name.